# ListView only populates on App Restart

Tags: android, listview, adapter, populate

I am having a problem with my ListView function. It is a simple listview with an arrayadapter. The array contains strings. However the data only populates whenever I restart the app. It doesn't populate as soon as the activity starts.

```
public void setTemp() {
    carpoolView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.carpoolsList);
    carpoolView.invalidateViews();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objectIds);

    carpoolView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_pools);
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    String currentUserName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("fullName").toString();
    ActionBar mp = getActionBar();
    mp.setTitle(currentUserName +"'s Carpools");
    mp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    receiveCarpools();
    //setList();
    setTemp();


    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Where is `setTemp()` being called from?

Comment: Also, there is no need to invalidate your views (line 3 of your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all

Why dont Cast your ListView in onCreate method, are you using Activity, Fragment?, so the questions is why you are Casting the ListView item in your internal function?...

Second, as people said before, if your adapter, or in this case objectIds change, to notify it to your adapter you must use

```
carpoolView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to tell you to your adapter that your data changed, and so it must be updated.

When are you calling your function?, that could be the error too.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a good tutorial from vogella on how to use listviews.

Basically, you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter to notify it needs to update the view from the model of the listview.

So when using setTemp(), call this onCreateView() for your Activity/Fragment to populate the list initially.  If you modify the model of the listview, e.g. to add a new list item, you will need to let the adapter know that the data model has changed using the notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyDataSetInvalidated() call.  Like so

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You need to avoid creating a new adapter every time you setTemp() as well.  This is a bit of a waste of resources to create adapters each time and let the old adapter get garbage collected.  Recommend using a global field for the adapter that can be persistent for your data model so you can always notify it when things change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function at the last line.Hope it works for you.

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```